# Setting a limit or Disable scroll top

Tags: javascript, css

So I've been doing this navbar that slides down once it reach its section, like for example the "about" nav-item will slide down when it reach it's section. however I don't know how can i set a limit for this to disable once it reach other section.

here's what's happening

I have here my nav item in m landing page
[image]

once the nav item reach its section, its slides down and left.
[image]

but when it reaches other section, still it's highlighted.
[image]

I want it to get back on its size once it reaches the bottom of iths section.

Here's my code. I am trying to put a limit like >800 & < 1499 but no effect is happening.

```
        <script>
            $(window).scroll(function() {               
                $('.aboutMe').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 800);
                $('.myPortfolio').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 1500);
                $('.contactMe').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 2250);
            });
        </script>
```

in CSS:

```
  .aboutMe.scrolled {
    background-color: #495633;
    border: solid 1px #495633;
    color: white;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200%;
    animation: changeColor .5s; 
} 


.myPortfolio.scrolled {
    background-color: #c7ad66;
    border: solid 1px #c7ad66;
    color: white;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200%;
    animation: changeColor .5s; 
} 


.contactMe.scrolled {
    background-color: #9c6766;
    border: solid 1px #9c6766;
    color: white;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200%;
    animation: changeColor .5s; 
} 

@keyframes changeColor {
    0% {
        height: 0%; width: 100px; 
    }
    50% {
        height: 200%; width: 100px;
    }
    100% {
        height: 200%; width: 300px;
    }
}
```

I'm getting back on track, I stop coding for almost 4 years and now I've been started to learn it all over again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using the scrolltop value of the document.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var tmpScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (tmpScrollTop > 800) {
        $(".aboutMe").addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
        $(".aboutMe").removeClass("scrolled");
    }

    if (tmpScrollTop > 1500) {
        $(".myPortfolio").addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
        $(".myPortfolio").removeClass("scrolled");
    }

    if (tmpScrollTop > 2250) {
        $(".contactMe").addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
        $(".contactMe").removeClass("scrolled");
    }
});
```